# How to use the array modifier multiple times in an optimised way?

Tags: modifiers, geometry

I've been doing some visualisation exercises and I had this question. I want to recreate

[image: this shape].

I planned to do this by creating a 1x1 cube and then cloning it using the array modifier, but I am not sure how to correctly use this tool.

[image: count is 4 and -1 is the relative offset in y direction]

After this, if I try to add another array modifier, it overrides the previous parameters.

I did not apply the modifier yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array modifier takes whatever is above it in the modifier stack and creates duplicates based on the offset(s) you choose: constant, relative or object based (or a combo of all three). These arrays are additive with the arrays below in the modifier stack. That means if you have 1 unit cube with a relative offset of 1 on X and a count of 3 followed by a second array with a relative offset of 1 on Y with a count of 3, you will end up with a 3x3x1 rectangle lying flat on the X-Y plane.

One way to do what you want to do is extrude faces instead of arraying the cube. You can then use a textures to get the visualization you want. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You *could* do this using arrays, because they can be given Start and End Caps which can, themselves, be arrays. But you would be creating a lot of work for yourself.

when you put a second Array modifier on an object, it doesn't override the previous parameters; it generates an array with the entire previous array as its elements.

You might be better off using a different duplication method - perhaps [Vertex Instancing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/verts.html#verts):

[image]

.. using a simple framework of vertices. Every time you <kbd>E</kbd>(<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>) extrude a new vertex, a cube will be instanced on it.

[image]

Comment: These are really interesting ideas. I wasn't aware of vertex instancing at all!

Comment: @Electric_Wizard I think yours is better for contiguous cubes.. :)